# Form not attaching file after I check to make sure there is a file present

Tags: php, forms, email, attachment

I'm making a form that submits remarks and uploads a file and emails it as an attachment. The problem I am having is if I don't attach a file, the PHP doesn't know what to attach. So to fix this, I changed

```
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);      // attachment
```

To:

```
if($file != "")
      {
      $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);      // attachment
      }
```

Now, it is not submitting attachments even if I put them in, how would I fix this?

Full Code:

```
<title>Success</title>
 <?php
    require_once '../PHPMailer_5.2.2/class.phpmailer.php';

$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$phone = $_POST['phone'] ;
$gender = $_POST['gender'] ;
$recipientname = $_POST['recipientname'] ;
$hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'] ;
$age = $_POST['age'] ;
$school = $_POST['school'] ;
$pet = $_POST['pet'] ;
$hair = $_POST['hair'] ;
$eye = $_POST['eye'] ;
$food = $_POST['food'] ;
$drink = $_POST['drink'] ;
$sport = $_POST['sport'] ;
$schoolsubject = $_POST['schoolsubject'] ;
$teacher = $_POST['teacher'] ;
$strengths = $_POST['strengths'] ;
$animal = $_POST['animal'] ;
$superpower = $_POST['superpower'] ;
$fears = $_POST['fears'] ;
$skills = $_POST['skills'] ;
$dedication = $_POST['dedication'] ;
$friend = $_POST['friend'] ;
$otherinfo = $_POST['otherinfo'] ;
$file = $_POST['file'] ;

$body = "Name: $name
Email: $email
Gender: $gender
Recipient's name: $recipientname
Hobbies: $hobbies
Age: $age
School: $school
Pet Info: $pet
Hair Color: $hair
Eye Color: $eye
Favorite Food: $food
Favorite Drink $drink
Favorite Sport: $sport
Favorite School Subject: $schoolsubject
Favorite Teacher: $teacher
Strengths: $strengths
Favorite Animal: $animal
Favorite Superpower/Why: $superpower
Fears/Challenged: $fears
Skills: $skills
Dedication: $dedication
Best Friend Info: $friend
Other Information: $otherinfo";

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

    try {
      $mail->AddAddress('***@****.com', 'Michael');
      $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
      $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
      $mail->Subject = "Message From Legendmaker Customer: $name";
      $mail->Body = $body;

      $mail->Send();
      echo "Story Request Sent Successfully</p>\n";
      echo "<img src='/images/knight-success.png' alt='success' width='429' height='791' />"; 
      echo "Your request will be processed soon. Once your request has been processed you will receive an email. </p>\n";
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST['file'] doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.

I would remove that and put:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['size']) {
    ...
}
```

Would that work?

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I appreciate everyone's patience with me while I learn PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if `$_POST['file']` is equal to `""` is not a valid way of checking if the user uploaded a file. You want something like [is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/is_uploaded_file).